# Как проверить сколько четных-нечетных цифр в числе введенном с клавиатуры

Tags: java

Допустим при вводе числа 41235 чтобы выдало, что четных чисел в числе 2, нечетных 3.

Comment: получите остаток от деления на 2 для каждой цифры.

Comment: я бы каждое число закинул в массив, а потом циклом прогнать на нахождение как пишет tym

Comment: @VladZherihov их не обязательно даже в числа переводить, можно просто `(mystring.charAt(i) - '0') % 2 == 0` и все дела

Answer (score 2):

Быстрое и понятное решение без преобразований и лишних аллокаций

```
    String s = "41235";
    int odd = 0, even = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        if ((s.charAt(i) - '0') % 2 == 0) even++;
        else odd++;

    System.out.println("odd: "  + odd + " even: " + even);
```

Вывод

```
odd: 3 even: 2
```

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev замеров не делал, а с чем это сравнивать? Вы в своем ответе парсите же строку, это по идее явно медленней, чем конвертировать char в int, разве нет?

Comment: Можно просто посмотреть на младший бит `s.charAt(i)` (0 -- четное) (но лучше все же проверить, что этот символ `c >= '0' && c <= '9'`)

Comment: @avp согласен, это даст некоторый выигрыш в скорости, просто не хотел усложнять код проверками и битовыми операциями, сам в них не очень силен, если честно :)

Comment: Оказывается в Java тоже есть [isdigit()](http://proglang.su/java/characters-isdigit), так что проверки упрощаются -)

Comment: @avp  да, я его тоже заметил, он в соседнем ответе используется.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "41235";

Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> r = s.chars()
                                 .filter(Character::isDigit)
                                 .map(c -> Character.digit(c, 10))
                                 .boxed()
                                 .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(i -> i % 2 == 0));

System.out.println("Чётных: " + r.get(true).size());
System.out.println("Нечётных: " + r.get(false).size());
```

или

```
String s = "41235";

int even = 0;
int odd = 0;
for (String n : s.split("")) {
    if (Integer.valueOf(n) % 2 == 0)
        even++;
    else
        odd++;
}

System.out.println("Чётных: " + even);
System.out.println("Чётных: " + odd);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int count = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    
    while (count > 0) {
        if (count % 2 ==0) {
            even++;
        }
            else
            {
            odd++;
            }
            count = count / 10;
        }
        System.out.println("Even: " + even + " Odd: "+ odd);
```

Comment: По моему тут не хватает разбора строки на символы, т.к. readLine считывает всё до конца строки. Либо надо использовать вместо этого просто read, тогда будет посимвольно.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = scanner.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; a/i > 0; i *= 10) {
        if ((a / i) % 2 == 0)
            even++;
        else
            odd++;
    }
    System.out.println("Even: " + even + " Odd: " + odd);
```

Comment: Почему вы написали ещё один ответ,  а не поправили ранее данный?